# Installing new deeper farmhouse sink

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I have a new sink to install and unfortunately the alignment of the disposal pipe to the wall drain is too close to call. I am thinking of capping that waste connection (white connection) and installing a new lower connection on the pipe being used for the dishwasher drain (pipe with disposal hose zip tied) I can install a new connection 3-4” lower and will be able to have the disposal pipe 1-2” above the drain fitting. [image]

Comment: Loosen all the tighteners and play around with lining stuff up.

Comment: There isn't a question here....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The connection where the white pipe joins can be lowered by at least 1-1/2" maybe even 2" by removing that black piece and trimming it shorter (or just replacing it with an off-the-shelf shorter piece).

Answer (score 1):

You can run the disposal drain into the drain pipe the DW is now tied to.

The DW then can be run into the disposal.  Just be sure to have a loop higher than the sink drain.